# Django: why Using a custom user model when starting a project is not made compulsory?

Tags: django, django-users

I was working on a project and after the mid way, i wanted to work on the users. That time i decided to use email as the login. I found that custom user migration should be done only in the start of the project.

> **Using a custom user model when starting a project**
>
> If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a
>   custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for
>   you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but
>   you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

So why such a thing should not be made as compulsory thing before one starts a project.

Assuming I am in the middle of a project. How can i transfer all the database data to my new project with custom_user.

Comment: Making a custom user compulsory would make it slightly harder to get started, but would stop users being stuck with the default `User` model later. It might be worth suggesting on the [django-developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-developers) mailing list. if it hasn't been discussed before. Backwards compatibility might be an issue. Also note that not all Django projects use `django.contrib.auth`  at all.

Comment: As for the second part of your answer, there isn't an easy solution to migrate to a new project with a custom user.

Comment: which auth is preffered other than `django.contrib.auth`

Comment: I meant, some projects do not need auth at all so they don't use `django.contrib.auth`. There isn't a preferred alternative.

Comment: you mean they dont have any users and groups, you talking about that kind of projects

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in the middle of a project without any problem but if you use "User model" in your apps it make some conflict so you should delete or rename DB and migrations file, So if you want to keep your data i think you can use "Fixtures" to reload the Database. something like this:

```
python manage.py dumpdata APPNAME --format json --indent 4 > APPNAME_FOLDER/fixtures/APPNAME.json
```

and save your data in json format.
*APPNAME* refers to the app that you want keep data